# Two related iOS apps in one CocoaPods workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode5, cocoapods

I am working together with some friends on a iOS project.

We are using CocoaPods for integrating third-party code (Facebook-iOS-SDK, ..) and sync the whole Xcode workspace (including the Pods Project) with Git and bitbucket.

Everything works perfect and we are very happy with this setup.

The only problem is, that we have to build a second application and the two apps will share a lot of common code.

Does it make sense to just add a second target to the workspace or is it better to create a private pod?
Other possibilities? We want't to keep things as simple as possible...

Comment: i think you should create framework with common code and add it to projects as dependency.

Comment: There is a q n a forum you can post to at cocoapods. URL not handy.